# NameError: name 'Title' is not defined (Why is 'Title' not defined)

Tags: python, syntax-error

The  code below works until the final line:

```
writer.writerow([Title, Views, Likes, Dislikes, datetime.now()])
```

and I receive this error:

```
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-1666dd7f773b> in <module>()
----> 1 writer.writerow([Title, Views, Likes, Dislikes, datetime.now()])

NameError: name 'Title' is not defined
```

Can someone tell me what going on???? (Using python2 with Jupyter)

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import requests



myurl = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sports'





page = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sports")
page.status_code


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup
link_list = []

for link in soup.select('div.yt-lockup-content a[href^=/watch]'):
    newLink = link.attrs.get('href')
    link_list.append(newLink)

print(link_list[0:6])

index = range(len(link_list))
columns = ['Links', 'Title', 'Views', 'Likes', 'Dislikes']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

df['Links'] = link_list
df['Links'] = 'https://www.youtube.com/' + df['Links']


for i in range(len(link_list)):
    if i<5 or i>len(link_list)-5:
        print('{} out of {}'.format(i, len(link_list)))


    html = urlopen(df['Links'][i]).read()
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))

    df['Title'][i] = soup.title.get_text()
    df['Views'][i] = int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '',soup.select('.watch-view-count')[0].get_text().split()[0]))


    df['Title'][i] = soup.title.get_text()
    df['Views'][i] = int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', soup.select('.watch-view-count')[0].get_text().split()[0]))


    a = str(soup.find_all('button', \
      attrs={'title': 'I like this'})).replace(",","")
    df['Likes'][i] = float(re.findall(r'\d+', a)[0])


    a = str(soup.find_all('button', \
      attrs={'title': 'I dislike this'})).replace(",","")
    df['Dislikes'][i] =  float(re.findall(r'\d+', a)[0])


print(df.sort_values('Views', ascending = False).head())


print(df.sort_values('Views', ascending = False))

with open('youtube.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([Title, Views, Likes, Dislikes, datetime.now()])
```

Comment: Why did you think any of those variables *would* be defined?

Comment: Looks like you need  `df.to_csv()`

Comment: The first item of your row is a list; the first four items in that list are variable names that appear nowhere else in the program.  What do you expect this statement to do?

Comment: Please reduce your code snippet to the smallest chunk that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
writer.writerow([Title, Views, Likes, Dislikes, datetime.now()])
```

you are using `Title` and not `"Title"`. Python is interpreting this to mean `Go find the variable Title and put its value here`. When what you are really trying to do is pass the string value `"Title"`. You need to put `Title`, `Views`, `Likes`, and `Dislikes` all in quotes.